# which android,mk file has this?

Tags: android, makefile

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS+= -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -m64

LOCAL_CFLAGS+= -Wmissing-prototypes -Winline
```

Hi guys so im just wondering which android make file has these? im having trouble finding it in the vast size of the aosp!!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't feel comfortable using grep, you can use http://androidxref.com/. This tool indexes the source code of most major branches of AOSP and makes it easier to search the codebase.

I started the search parameters for androidxref for you [here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/search?q=LOCAL_CFLAGS&defs=&refs=&path=Android.mk&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools)